Community Promotion Ads — 2020
2020 has come! But… oops, where did the time go? It’s already March! Belated as it is, it’s time for a refresh of Community Promotion Ads!
What are Community Promotion Ads?
Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.
Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

relevant blogs and websites
cryptography conferences, meetups, or other events
anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about the stuff your community deems important. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are relevant to your own community's interests, both for those already in the community and those yet to join. 
Why do we reset the ads every year?
Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.
The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.
How does it work?
The answers you post to this question must conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored. 

All answers should be in the exact form of:
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url 

Please do not add anything else to the body of the post. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
The question must always be tagged with the magic community-ads tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

Image requirements

The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
Must be GIF or PNG
No animated GIFs
Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

Score Threshold
There is a minimum score threshold an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.
You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats here.

Last year's stats can be found here (which may be more conclusive than the current empty list for this year :p). 2018 2017 2016 2015



This ad was originally submitted by mikeazo in 2016.



This ad was originally submitted by e-sushi in 2017.



This ad was originally submitted by e-sushi in 2017.



This ad was originally submitted by Maeher in 2019.



This ad was originally submitted by e-sushi in 2017.



This ad was originally submitted by Harald Schilly in 2016.



Given how bad crypto answers are on SO, I don't think this is reasonable. “Want to help make software security suck less? Answer [cryptography] questions on SO” would be better.

This ad was originally submitted by Ilmari Karonen in 2017.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I agree with the sentiment but lack the skills (and time to learn the skills) to make the required modification to the sources which Ilmari linked to be here (a "simple" SVG) and I would probably prefer a less "aggressive" wording.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' At least 10% of the questions have reasonable answers, cause I wrote them: 11,583 questions, 1199 answers that I wrote :P But I still would not advice people to follow the tag. And yes, I would certainly like some help.
